# How to give output based on MessageBox input with Select Case?

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2012

How do you give output based on MessageBox input?

**ie.** I have a application which shows a MessageBox on button click. The MessageBox has buttons Abort, Retry, and Ignore.
I want to make it so on clicking each button, I want to display a MessageBox with different text.

**Eg:** On clicking Abort, I want to display a MessageBox with text "Aborted".
On clicking Retry, I want to display a MessageBox with text "Retried".
On clicking Ignore, I want to display a MessageBox with text "Ignored".

My attempt was: (I get a error: A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll.
Additional information: Conversion from string "Input" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.)
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Input_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Input.Click
        Dim a As DialogResult = MsgBox("Click anything.", "Input", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore)

```
    Select Case a
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort
            MsgBox("Aborted", "Abort")
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Retry
            MsgBox("Retried", "Retry")
        Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Ignore
            MsgBox("Ignored", "Ignore")
    End Select
End Sub
```

End Class

***PS: Use of Select Case would be preferred.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go mate.

```
 Dim a As DialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Click anything.", "Input", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore)

Select Case a
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Abort
                Console.WriteLine("Aborted")
            Case Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel
                Console.WriteLine("Cancel")
        End Select
```

Comment: :D WORKED! Weird that you have to use MessageBox.Show.   MsgBox used to work for me.

Comment: MsgBox() returns an integer. MessageBox.Show() returns a DialogResult.